# Upper Bounds on a Ratio Concerning the Sum of Divisors

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum

Given that $n$ is an [highly abundant number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_abundant_number), what is a function $f(x)$ that is a tight upper bound on the ratio: $$\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{n}$$ where $\sigma_1(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$ (including $n$ itself). I also want to know an upper bound if $n$ is a [superabundant number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superabundant_number)

$f(x)$ doesn't have to reach equality on certain numbers, but it would be optimal if it did.

Comment: I first learned this sort of material from Nicolas, a very nice article, including discussion of his student G. Robin... http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf  which emphasizes Ramnujan's Superior Highly Composite numbers, but explains the (common) construction very well. The exact bounds you ask about are discussed in my http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79927/which-n-maximize-gn-frac-sigmann-log-log-n  .  By the way, you seem to want some kind of exact formula that also gives perfect equality at certain numbers; this is not going to be available.

Comment: The bound doesn't have to reach equality at certain numbers, but it would be nice if it did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

umm. For $n \geq 16,$ we get $\log \log n > 1, $ using log base $e = 2.71828...$ Then for $n \geq 16,$
$$  \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n}  $$
does have an upper bound.

From  Robin we have an unconditional result (1984) that says that your ratio of interest is, for $n \geq 13,$ smaller than
$$  \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n} < e^\gamma + \frac{0.64821364942...}{(\log \log n)^2},$$ with the constant in the numerator giving equality for $n=12.$ Note $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649,$ while $e^\gamma \approx 1.7810724$

In particular, for $n \geq 268,$ we get $  \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n} < 2$  Below are the ratios bigger than $1.9$ with $n \geq 3.$

```
  14.17718374918197           3
   5.357674360663709          4
   2.521617642462445          5
   3.429366566700587          6
   2.561127739941722          8
   2.158189420874225         10
   2.563440313761713         12
   2.041357661635523         18
   1.913982525796606         20
   2.162126621182643         24
   1.960580021444964         30
   1.980481186664786         36
   1.908540572163114         48
   1.98636974867664          60
   1.915700702020492        120
```

Comment: Yes, but that's assuming RH, I want unconditional bounds. The bound doesn't have to reach equality at certain numbers, but it would be nice if it did.

Comment: @QuoteDave no, this is unconditional. See http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Robin_1984.pdf

Comment: Sorry, it's in French, so I have no idea what it says. Could you just give me the gist of it, or send me the English version? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no upper bound.  The sum of divisor function is multiplicative.  If $p$ is prime, we have $\frac {\sigma_1(p^n)}{p^n}=\frac {p^{n+1}-1}{p^n(p-1)}\gt 1+\frac 1p$.  If we multiply a lot of these together for different primes we get 
$$\left(1+\frac 1p\right)\left(1+\frac 1q\right)\left(1+\frac 1r\right)\ldots \gt 1+\frac 1p + \frac 1q + \frac 1r +\ldots$$
and we know the sum of the inverses of the primes diverges.

Comment: what's the point of $n$? $\frac{\sigma(p)}{p} = 1+\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: @mathworker21:  I wanted to handle cases where the prime was to a higher power.  Many abundant numbers have primes to higher powers.  You are right that it makes things easier.

Comment: @RossMillikan I do not expect a tight bound that is a number, but a function $f(x)$.