# Maxima of the Sum of Divisors Function and Upper Bound of a similar Ratio

Tags: maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum

If we define a function (aka Gronwall’s function) as: $$F(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n}$$

Then for $n>15$, it does have an upper bound. I want to know what's that specific upper bound is?

Also when exactly does the maxima of the divisor sum function ${\sigma(n)}$ occur? Is it at superabundant numbers or something else?

I know that the minima occurs at prime numbers where if n is a prime number then $\sigma(n)=n+1$, but I'm not sure about it's maxima.

This question was inspired from the answer given by Will Jagy here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3300005

Comment: Your maximum occurs at $n = 24.$  This must happen at a superabundant number, simply because $ \log \log n$  is increasing. The numbers to look at for  surprisingly large values of $\sigma(n) $  are the colossally   abundant numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number   There is no upper bound for $\sigma(n)$ or $ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}  $